# How to compile and link only few files in Visual Studio and exclude other files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I am working on a Visual Studio C++ project which uses Oracle as DB. I have refactored it now it supports PostgreSQL as well. I am using a Macro to choose b/w Oracle and PostgreSQL. When we run the code it requires client dll for both Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Since its decided at compile time only which DB to use, so is it possible to compile and link only Oracle or PostgreSQL related code and library? One possible solution is to have 2 different codebase for both. Another solution I can think is to create 2 different libraries and link accordingly but I have no idea how achieve that.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: I recommend you create *three* new DLL projects in your workspace: One each for the database-specific code, then one for the common interface. Your application references the common interface DLL, which could have two configurations depending on which concrete database it should build with.

Comment: Or learn how to load and use DLL's at runtime. Then you put the two different database codes in two different DLL projects, and the application select and use one or the other at runtime.

Comment: If you need to link the DLL, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170), it will help you.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT Thanks but I am aware about how o create dll and my db utility is indeed a dll only. The DB utility has 4 components for now.
1) Oracle supporting code
2) PostgreSQL DB supporting code
3) Interface for above two
4) Common functionality 

What I'm looking for is to only compile and link from either option 1 or option 2 mentioned above. 
Common functionality

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically load the dll:

```
if( using dll  A...)
{
...

// the function to load 
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)(DWORD,UINT);
...

HINSTANCE hDLL;               // Handle to DLL
LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc1;    // Function pointer
DWORD dwParam1;
UINT  uParam2, uReturnVal;

hDLL = LoadLibrary("MyDLL");
if (hDLL != NULL)
{
   lpfnDllFunc1 = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL,
                                           "DLLFunc1");
   if (!lpfnDllFunc1)
   {
      // handle the error
      FreeLibrary(hDLL);
      return SOME_ERROR_CODE;
   }
   else
   {
      // call the function
      uReturnVal = lpfnDllFunc1(dwParam1, uParam2);
   }
}
```

For  your  reference: API [GetProcAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/getprocaddress?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(GetProcAddress)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170)